# How to add custom module's tasks into Calendar SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created a custom module(Lunch), how can I add these tasks into the Calendar, like Meetings, Calls, etc are being shown into the Calendar.

Also, how to add Scheduling panel into Custom module's Edit View in SuiteCRM?
[image]

PS. I have searched everywhere, but not finding any leading or related material.

Comment: For adding any custom module in the calendar, check calendar logic that how it is fetching existing records of certain modules, you can modify it and add logic to fetch your custom module,

Comment: Adding scheduler panel in a custom module, check out existing module, it uses its own js and tpl files for that view. It is added in edit view then. If you study existing code then you will get the complete overview of the existing implementation and you can modify it according to your need.